# How to solve 'This field is required' for django forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I created a blog like app. Whenever I update an entry and press the submit button, I want it to take me to view page for that blog entry. However it just redirects me to the update page. When I check form.errors it says that 'This field is required' for all of the fields.  But all of the fields are filled with data.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{{ form.as_p }}
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
       
        <input type="submit" value="Update">
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your form declared in the wrong block:

```py
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Update">
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Notice that the `{{form.as_p}}` has to be declared into the form block.

If you fill all data but your form is out of the `form` tag then the data will not be send.

Comment: Thank you. That solved the problem. Cant believe I spent so much time troubleshooting and the answer was right there.